# How to get coordinates of a point on a polyline by meters?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, polyline

I loop along an MVCArray ... trying to split the segments by an offset.

But I would require a little more precision to split the poly-line at the proper points.

Basically I just would need to know how to calculate a point on a line between 2 points - defined by the last few meters.

Or is there any way to insert a verticle at this position?

Talking of Maps API V3.

Comment: start point, bearing, distance is known, but what formula returns LatLng for that?

Comment: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.js looks promising.